# How to open a project page in silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, navigation

There are two pages in my silverlight project: MainPage-default page and SecondViewPage an added Silverlight page.
To navigate from one to another, I've overridden the Application_Startup(...)

```
{
this.RootVisual = mainUI;
mainUI.Children.Add(new MainPage());
}
```

created a

```
public static void GotoPage(UserControl nextPage)
        {
            App app = (App)Application.Current;
            app.mainUI.Children.Clear();
            //show next page
            app.mainUI.Children.Add(nextPage);
        }
```

Then openning the SecondViewPage is simple like:

```
App.GotoPage(new SecondViewPage());
```

But what I realy want is to open the second view page in a separage *browser* window because the removing childer and adding new makes navigation totally outside of the browser (the "back" button is not keeping the prvious page link).

Thanks for suggestions.
V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of problem that the navigation framework is designed to solve.

I recommend you clear half an hour and watch this [Silverlight TV Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Creating-Navigation-Structures-in-Silverlight-Silverlight-TV-38) on Channel 9.

**Edit**

If you must launch a separate window you the navigation framework would still be useful however you would use a standard window navigation.  Like this:-

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("ThisHostPage.aspx#SecondView" UriKind.Relative), "_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, but the navigation is not what is needed. It will still paint my second page into the frame of the "switch board". But I need to open a separate browser and load my "second page" into. V

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not be using any navigation features provided by Silverlight 4.

I recommend you try generating a test project using the "Business Application" template and see how multipage navigation *can* work. It has full support for browser back and forward and will save you a lot of work.

Comment: Same as in Anthony's response, I don't want to paint my next page into a frame not to loose "full screen" and page real estate.  Just open a new browser window and load my page fully. Thanks,V